# Using a Dictionary in a linq query inside Contains method

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to select items for which I have mapping in my dictionary

This is what Ia m trying to do

```
    var columnsMapping = (from dc in sourceTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                          where dc.ColumnName.Contains(columnsMappingDictionary.Keys.GetEnumerator())
                          select new
                          {
                              columnName = dc.ColumnName,
                              columnType = dc.DataType
                          }).ToDictionary(key => key.columnName, value => value.columnType);
```

My dictionary is of type (string,string).

I keep getting this error

```
The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.KeyCollection.Enumerator' to 'string'
```

Can anyone help me correct my piece of code.

Comment: Just like the error says, you are passing an `Enumerator` when you should be passing a `string` to the `.Contains()` method.

Comment: why using GetEnumerator()? because it doesn't return a string

Comment: I thought that since my "key" is a string, a GetEnumerator() would give me a string and then I could do the comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what semantic you had in mind with your `where` condition. I see two possibilities:

- You want to apply `dc.ColumnName.Contains(...)` to every key in the dictionary, or
- You want to check `dc.ColumnName` against the existing dictionary keys,

I discuss both situations below.

Here is how you match a string against a set of keys:

```
where columnsMappingDictionary.Keys.Any(key => dc.ColumnName.Contains(key))
```

This condition is true when `dc.ColumnName` has any of the keys as its substring.

Here is how you check if `dc.ColumnName` is present among the keys of the `columnsMappingDictionary`:

```
where columnsMappingDictionary.ContainsKey(dc.ColumnName)
```

Answer (score 2):

Vice versa:
`where columnsMappingDictionary.Keys.Contains(dc.ColumnName))`